# Office 365 API - Embed image

Tags: c#, office365, outlook-restapi

I am already successfully sending emails via the api. I now need to try and embed an image to the footer of the email.
I am running a wpf c# app and have loaded the image to my system and set it as content build type so I can get a handle on it.
The api requires a string as the body.
I have created an HTML email format via the stringbuilder class.
I am using the following code to try and embed the image.

```
sb.Append("<p style=\"text-align: left;\">&nbsp;</p>");

        var avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(sb.ToString(), null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
        string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\images\fordEmail.jpg";
        var inline = new LinkedResource(path, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
        inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(inline);

        sb.Append(String.Format(@"<img src=""cid:{0}"" />", inline.ContentId));


        return sb.ToString();
```

The image appears on the email but as a dead link, red cross.
I'm not sure if I have to attach the image first or maybe render out to base64?
Any help would be gratefully accepted.
Thanks Scott

EDIT:
Code for API

```
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = new ItemBody() { Content = body, ContentType = BodyType.HTML };
await client.Me.SendMailAsync(mail, true);
```

EDIT
Jason seems to be getting me along the right route. But I read somewhere that it may need saving as a draft and then sending.
My mail api code is as follows;

```
mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = new ItemBody() { Content = body, ContentType = BodyType.HTML };
            await client.Me.Messages.AddMessageAsync(mail);
            var messageId = mail.Id;
            string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\images\fordEmail.jpg";
            Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
            byte[] arr;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                arr = ms.ToArray();
            }

            mail.Attachments.Add(new FileAttachment()
            {
                IsInline = true,
                ContentBytes = arr,
                Name = "fordEmail.jpg",
                ContentId = "my_inline_attachment"
            });

            await client.Me.Messages[messageId].SendAsync();
```

and the page content (as requested)

```
<p><strong>Automated message from xxx.</strong></p><p>*Amendment from previous notification</p><style type="text/css">.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#aabcfe;}.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 50px 10px 10px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aabcfe;color:#669;background-color:#e8edff;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;}.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;text-align-left;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 50px 10px 10px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aabcfe;color:#039;background-color:#b9c9fe;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;}p  {font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px}p.padding {padding-right: 50px}p.smallFont {font-size:9px}</style><p>Flight xxx has now arrived. Please find the details below;&nbsp;</p><table class="tg"><tr><th class="tg-031e" colspan="2" text-alight:left>Flight Details</th></tr><tr><td class="tg-031e"<p>Date</p></td><td class="tg-031e"<p class="DecimalAligned">07/05/2015</p></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-031e"<p>Flight</p></td><td class="tg-031e"<p class="DecimalAligned">xxx469J</p></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-031e"<p>Route</p></td><td class="tg-031e"<p class="DecimalAligned">DUB -&nbsp;FNC</p></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-031e"<p class="padding">Scheduled / Actual Time Departure</p></td><td class="tg-031e"<p class="DecimalAligned">07:10 / 12:00 (UTC)</p></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-031e"<p>Scheduled / Actual Time Arrival</p></td><td class="tg-031e"<p class="DecimalAligned">10:55 / 14:00 (UTC)</p></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-031e"<p>TOB</p></td><td class="tg-031e"<p class="DecimalAligned">100+1</p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class="smallFont"><em>Source: xxx</em></span></p><p>Comments : TEST </p><p>Should you require any further information please do not hesitate to contact us </p><p>Operations Manager<br>xxx<br>t&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+44 (0) 111 111 111 – H24<br>s&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;xxx<br>e&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:xxx">xxx</a></p><p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p><img src="cid:my_inline_attachment" />
```

Still no attachment.
Thanks

Comment: What does the body of the mail looks like during your test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the answer with the help of this stock overflow question.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031435/office-365-send-email-with-attachment-using-outlookservicesclient)

The key to this is the

```
// Update with attachments
await m.UpdateAsync();
// Send the message
await m.SendAsync();
```

Seems a problem with the API at the moment. Thanks for all your help on this. Hopefully this will help others out.
Scott

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to attach the file, and be sure to set `IsInline` to `true` and the `ContentId` property to the same value you use in the HTML markup. See this post for the raw REST equivalent: [How do I send Email with inline Attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377376/how-do-i-send-email-with-inline-attachments).